# how to not show translate request in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

chrome sends a translate request to user when the website language has different with user's local language my question is how can I set app language with multiple language so that chrome can not recognize it to make the request

I tried to add 'lang' to html body tag  in `index.html` file

```
 <body lang="de">
```

but nothing changed

Comment: I would try this: ```<html lang="en">```

Comment: i treid it in html tag but with `lang="de"`and it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For future reference**

Add the language attribute to the `html tag` like so:

```
<html lang="de">
```